# With genindex is it possible to have multiple auto-generated indexes that are scoped to separate chapters?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

With the following RST, Sphinx automatically generates one index for the entire documentation.

```
#####
Index
#####

.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   genindex
```

I would like to split the index into multiple indexes based on the chapters of my documentation so that each index only contains references to the respective chapter. Is that possible?

Comment: For what are you generating? Is it a Python documentation or some other kind of document?

Comment: The documentation currently is basically continuous text with some MathJax. I plan on including on some TypeScript of mine with [sphinx-js](https://github.com/mozilla/sphinx-js), later on though.